# Estrutura sintática, verbos

Tags: verbos, sintaxe

Os verbos em suas formas nominais caracterizam uma frase como oração e se classificam consequentemente como núcleo de um predicado verbal?

Comment: Umas vezes sim, outras não. Tens algum caso específico em mente?

Comment: Respondeu minha pergunta.